# StackExchange.Redis command timeout problem

Tags: c#, .net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

In my project, I use a *singleton* `ConnectionMultiplexer` and create `IDataBase` object everywhere whenever I needed. It worked just fine until recent days. We found exceptions like below:

> Timeout awaiting response (outbound=0KiB, inbound=0KiB, 6484ms elapsed, timeout is 5000ms), command=GET, next: SET cece154b2cf4a1488c9062fda469aa63, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 13, aw: False, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 1307, in-pipe: 0, out-pipe: 0, serverEndpoint: ******, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: webapi2, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=7,Free=32760,Min=4,Max=32767), v: 2.2.4.27433

We checked the Redis server-side and all performance details look ok since the server workload is pretty low. Besides we never used any time-consuming commands like `keys *` (The slowlog shows slowest command was `flushdb`). Is there anything that I'm missing here?